# How do I actually implement the "sequence protocol" in Python practically speaing?

Tags: python, python-internals

If my python object returns 1 PySequence_Check how do I get it to return 0? Assuming my class implement **getitem**

Is there a way around this if my class implements **getitem** or that is hard to change?

""Return 1 if the object provides sequence protocol, and 0 otherwise. Note that it returns 1 for Python classes with a **getitem**() method unless they are dict subclasses since in general case it is impossible to determine what the type of keys it supports. This function always""succeeds.

document: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: I was hoping for an example that is concrete. I want to implement custom C code that changes this function for my specific python class example class Animal(object): def __get__item(self): return

Comment: You can find Python's definition of sequence [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). Basically Python is duck typing, if something works like a sequence (meaning implements those methods) then it is a sequence.

Comment: Are you writing your class in C, or in Python?

Comment: writing class in python

Comment: Then you can't and shouldn't change this.

Comment: @YiFei: That's a different concept of "sequence" from what PySequence_Check checks, useful in a different context. (For people not writing C extensions, it's usually a more *important* concept of "sequence" than what PySequence_Check checks, but we'd need more context to determine what's relevant for testgauss321's use case.)

Comment: @user2357112 how come?

Comment: Not sure what @user2357112supportsMonica means exactly. Hope the following helps. `PySequence_Check` checks if `<type>.tp_as_sequence` defines a `sq_item`, which is similar to `__getitem__` define from Python side (after excluding `dict` as the doc says). But it stops there. It doesn't check for `sq_length` which is the counterpart of `__len__`.